# php rest api not posting data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, api

Hi I am making this simple PHP REST API, its getting records from database but it is not posting,putting(updating) or deleting any record from mysql.

Below is sq for two tables in database one is spacecraft and other is armaments, I am tryig to post data into spacecrafts table..

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `xanda`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `spaceCraft`
--

CREATE TABLE `spaceCraft` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `crew` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `armament` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `spaceCraft`
--

INSERT INTO `spaceCraft` (`id`, `name`, `class`, `crew`, `image`, `value`, `status`, `armament`) VALUES
(1, 'Devastator', 'Star Destroyer', 35000, 'https:\\\\url.to.image', 2000, 'operational', 0),
(2, 'ROSETTA', 'Galaxy Explorer', 2300, 'http://image.com', 1889, 'Operational', 1);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `spaceCraft`
--
ALTER TABLE `spaceCraft`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `spaceCraft`
--
ALTER TABLE `spaceCraft`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

It is getting data but not posting or updating or deleting here is my php script

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'shoutit');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$response = array();
// echo $request_method; 

// Conditions for determining REQUEST METHOD
switch ($request_method)
 {
    case "GET":
response(metGet());
        break;

        case "POST":
        response(metPost());
        break;

        case  "DELETE":
        response(metDel());
        break;

        case "PUT":
        response(metPut());
        break;

}
// Function for get Request

function metGet()
{
    if (@$_GET['id'])
     {
        @$id = $_GET['id'];
        $where = "WHERE `id` = " .$id;
    }
    else
        {$id = 0;
            $where = "";

        }

    $dbhost  = 'localhost';    
  $dbname  = 'xanda';   // Modify these...
  $dbuser  = 'root';   // ...variables according
  $dbpass  = 'root';   // ...to your Database

  $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  if ($con->connect_error) die($con->connect_error);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM spaceCraft " . $where;
$result = $con->query($query);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $response[] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name'],"class"=>$row['class'],"crew"=>$row['crew'],"image"=>$row['image'],"value"=>$row['value'],"status"=>$row['status'],"armament"=>$row['armament']);
    // print_r($row);

}
return $response;
}

// Function for Post Request

function metPost()
{
    // echo "Post Method Called";

    if ($_POST)
     {

  $dbhost  = 'localhost';    
  $dbname  = 'xanda';   // Modify these...
  $dbuser  = 'root';   // ...variables according
  $dbpass  = 'root';   // ...to your Database

  $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  // if ($con->connect_error) die($con->connect_error);

  $query = "INSERT INTO `spaceCraft`(`id,`name`, `class`, `crew`, `image`, `value`, `status`, `armament`)
VALUES ('".$_POST['id']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['class']."','".$_POST['crew']."','".$_POST['image']."','".$_POST['value']."','".$_POST['status']."','".$_POST['arnament']."') or die (mysql_error())";


$result = $con->query($query);

if ($result == true or die($con->error)) 
    {
        echo "The Insert ID was: " . $result->insert_id;
        $response = array("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        $response = array("Failed");
    }
}

return $response;
}

// Function for Delete Request

function metDel()
{
        if ($_GET['id'])
     {

  $dbhost  = 'localhost';    
  $dbname  = 'xanda';   // Modify these...
  $dbuser  = 'root';   // ...variables according
  $dbpass  = 'root';   // ...to your Database

  $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  if ($con->connect_error) die($con->connect_error);

  $query = "DELETE FROM `spaceCraft` WHERE `id` = '".$_GET['id']. "'" ;
  $result = $con->query($query);

if ($result == true) 
    {
        $response = array("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        $response = array("Failed");
    }
}
return $response;
} 

// Function for Put Request

function metPut()
{
    // echo "Put Method Called";    
    if ($_POST)
     {

  $dbhost  = 'localhost';    
  $dbname  = 'xanda';   // Modify these...
  $dbuser  = 'root';   // ...variables according
  $dbpass  = 'root';   // ...to your Database

  $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  // if ($con->connect_error) die($con->connect_error);

  $query = "UPDATE  `spaceCraft` SET `name` = '".$_POST['name']."',
   `class` = '".$_POST["class"]."', `crew` '".$_POST["crew"]."', `image` = '".$_POST["image"]."', `value`= '".$_POST["value"]."', `status`= '".$_POST["status"]."' `armament` = '".$_POST["name"]."' WHERE `id` = '" . ($_POST['id']?$_POST['id']:$_GET['id']);


$result = $con->query($query);

if ($result == true) 
    {
        $response = array("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        $response = array("Failed");
    }
}

return $response;

}
//ENDPOINT
function response($response){
echo json_encode(array("message" => "Success" , "data" =>$response));
}
?>
```

Please look into it and help me out with post method update and delete

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206743/discussion-on-question-by-ashking-flawless-php-rest-api-not-posting-data-into-th).